# How to fix custom size of Google Maps marker in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

How do I set the marker size. Can anyone tell me?

[image: See This Image]

Comment: Please share the attempts you have made, and problems you've run into, so that others will have more context and can help you. For help, see “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: thank @jacefarm its working now

Comment: If an answer below solved your issue, be sure to **accept** the answer. If you discovered another answer on your own, you should submit and accept an answer to your own question, so that this question does not come up as "unanswered."

Comment: You should accept an answer or give one by yourself.so that if somebody else visits this question can know which answer resolved the problem correctly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's happening because the icon you are using as a marker is bigger in size.So,You can first convert it into Bitmap and change its size and then use that bitmap in as a custom marker. For example I have made a method which resizes your bitmap and returns the resized bitmap.

```
public Bitmap resizeBitmap(String drawableName,int width, int height){
    Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable", getPackageName()));
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, width, height, false);
}
```

Then call this method in `googleMap.addMarker()`

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("New Marker").position(yourGivenPosition).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resizeBitmap("your drawable name",72,64))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the dimensions of your Marker image (icon),  30 x 40 it's ok I think

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a `bmp` image since you are setting a custom marker.
To resize the `bmp`, use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (Bitmap src, int width, int height, boolean filter)`

Answer (score 1):

use Marker this way

```
<Marker
      anchor={{ x: 0.5, y: 1}}
      coordinate={location} 
>
      <Image style={styles.marker} source={image} />
    </Marker>
```