# Google maps custom marker too large

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

I am adding a custom marker to my map with code

```
marker =new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus)));
```

but it appears too large and covers the whole screen

[image]

how to solve this issue.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14851641/6950238) question an answers.

Comment: solved it. Thanks @AndriiOmelchenko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can resize  programmatically

**Solution 1:**

```
        int height = 100;
        int width = 100;
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bus);
        Bitmap b=bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
        Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
```

---

```
        MarkerOptions marker =   new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Your title")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker));
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

**Solution 2:**

Simple you need to  Change your Image into Small size.

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509791/how-to-fix-custom-size-of-google-maps-marker-in-android

Comment: Solution 1 fits to me, because I had Image from URL